# $\{0,1\}$-Matrices and Conjugation by Orthogonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be irreducible $\{0,1\}$ matrices and $S$ be an orthogonal matrix all of the same size $N$. Is it necessarily the case that if,

$A_1=SA_2S^T$

then $S$ is a permutation matrix?

Comment: No $A_1=A_2=Id$?

Comment: The question gets more interesting if one assumes that $A_1$ or $A_2$ are irreducible.

Comment: Toni Max - yes that was certainly an oversight.  I will edit to assume $A_1$ and $A_2$ are irreducible.

Comment: I've edited your question. I think you mean a $\{0,1\}$-matrix (with all entries equal to $0$ or $1$) rather than a $(0,1)$-matrix (whose elements lie inside the open interval $(0,1)$). If I have misunderstood your question, please feel free to roll back the edit.

Comment: Yes I meant a matrix with entries equal to either 0 or 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is no. Let
$$
S=\frac12\pmatrix{-1&1&1&1\\ 1&-1&1&1\\ 1&1&-1&1\\ 1&1&1&-1},\ J_2=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}
$$
and let also
$$
A=I_4,\ B=\pmatrix{J_2&0\\ 0&J_2},\ C=\pmatrix{0&I_2\\ I_2&0},\ D=\pmatrix{0&J_2\\ J_2&0}.
$$
One may verify that $S$ is real orthogonal and it commutes with each of $A,B,C$ and $D$. Moreover,
\begin{cases}
X_1=A+B+C+D,\\
X_2=A+B+C,\\
X_3=A+B+D,\\
X_4=B+C+D
\end{cases}
are irreducible $\{0,1\}$-matrices. Since $S$ commutes with $A,B,C,D$, we have $X_i=SX_iS^T$ for each $i$. Yet $S$ is not a permutation matrix.

The counterexample using $S$ and $X_1$ (the all-one matrix) above can be generalised to any other dimension $n\ge3$. Let $X$ be the $n\times n$ all-one matrix. Then
$$
S=\frac2nX-I
$$
is real orthogonal and $X=XS=SX=SXS^T$, but $S$ is not a permutation matrix.